# mysql max value from field after sum

Tags: mysql, sum, max

I want to know what crime is most likely to happen on each month. Right now I can get the max crime count in the data. but i want to sum all the fields that have the same offenceID field for that dateID and then get the max value.

[image: FYP_Crime table]

[image: FYP_Offence table]

[image: FYP_Date table]
Here is the code I have at the moment:

```
SELECT d.month, o.actualOffence, c.crimeCount
FROM (SELECT d2.dateID, d2.month, max(c2.crimecount) maxcrimecount
      FROM FYP_Date d2 JOIN FYP_Crime c2 ON d2.dateID=c2.dateID
      GROUP BY d2.dateID, d2.month) 
d JOIN FYP_Crime c ON d.dateID=c.dateID AND d.maxcrimecount = c.crimecount
        JOIN FYP_Offence o ON c.offenceID=o.offenceID
```

Comment: Do a few favors for everyone.  Can you put this on SQL Fiddle and can you use the code block so your SQL code is formatted for easy reading?  That will make the question easier for us to answer.

Comment: It's hard to figure this out without seeing the other tables in the query. And it would help if you showed the result you're trying to get.

Comment: Go to www.sqlfiddle.com and create a sample database.

Comment: If only there was some kind of Internet search engine for those 'how do I do that'-type questions

Comment: I added screenshots of the other tables.

Comment: what result you expect to get?

Comment: Well, you're improving, but please consider: If we want to solve your riddle then it's easier for us when we simply can cut'n'paste your DB definition (including INSERTs) and try out our approach. With screenshots we would have to build CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements on our own and have to thoroughly examine your screenshots. A DDL (as text) dramatically increases your chances of getting reasonable answers.

Comment: I want to get the month, actualOffence and crimeCount of the max value after it has added it all up. For example in my FYP_Crime table there are many offenceID 25 in the dateID 1, so i want to add these all up then get the max value.

Comment: your date handling is not the easiest - why is year included in column month?

Comment: @recycler From the other OP's questions I suppose the column is `char(7)` and contains `'YYYY-MM'`.

Comment: @PerlDog yes, the month should be 1 to 12 and year should be a separte column else the database has to covert string to int

Comment: It is stored as a char

Comment: @recycler Either that or store it as a date field with day always being `-01`. Depends on the context and/or intended queries.

Comment: I couldnt store it as date because i didnt have the date part of the date, so i stored as varchar because i am dealing with an actual dataset i couldnt just assume its the 01 of the month